# Is there any way of opening the output of a thread or child process in a new terminal. C++

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I am currently trying to make an OS simulation for my semester project, and I need to open the output of threads and child processes in a new terminal window so the output wont be messed up. Is there any way to do it in C++/ linux.

```
    pthread_t thread1;

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &usermodemenu, NULL); 

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
```

like the output of function usermodemenu( ) should open in a new terminal.

Comment: In a child process it should be possible to change what `stdout` refers to since it's a separate process. I don't think this would be possible with threads though -- since threads share the same process state

Comment: An answer to "*Is there any way to do it in C++*" is almost always "*Yes*". See here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51458898/how-do-i-open-multiple-separate-terminal-windows-in-c/51459100 Would I do it? No, probably not.

Comment: Cheap hack: Each thread writes to its own file and invokes `tail -f` on their file.